# Go chi renderer having difficult processing bound lists

Tags: go, compiler-errors, go-chi

Go here. Trying to get the chi renderer to return a list of `Order` struct instances and getting a compiler error that I don't understand:

```
package myapp

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/go-chi/render"
)

type Order struct {
    OrderId    string
  Status     string
}

func (*Order) Bind(r *http.Request) error {
    return nil
}

func GetAllOrderByCustomerId(dbClient DbClient, customerId string) http.HandlerFunc {
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // fetch all customer orders from the DB
    orders,err := dbClient.FetchAllOrdersByCustomerId(customerId)
    if err != nil {
      log.Error("unable to fetch orders for customer", err)
      render.Render(w, r, NewInternalServerError(err))
      return
    }

    render.Bind(r, &orders)
    return

  }
}
```

When I go to compile this code I get:

```
fizz/buzz/myapp/order_fetcher.go:136:20: cannot use &orders (type *[]Order) as type render.Binder in argument to render.Bind:
    *[]Order does not implement render.Binder (missing Bind method)
```

So even though I've defined a `Bind` for `Order`, it doesn't seem to automatically apply that `Bind` to a collection/list of `Orders`.

Can anyone see what I'm missing? Some endpoints will only be returning a single `Order`, whereas others (like this one) need to be able to return a collection/list of `Orders`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the example in `chi` repository, you have to create a helper method to ***render the list of something***, in your case, **list of orders.**

First, you have to implement the `render.Renderer` method then create a helper method to build a list of `render.Renderer`.

I've adapted your code from the example [here](https://github.com/go-chi/chi/blob/86f9a6e7ce9bf453eaa339b51f88f586edbccbc1/_examples/rest/main.go#L117):

```
type Order struct {
    OrderId string
    Status  string
}

// Render implement render.Renderer
func (*Order) Render(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    // do something
    return nil
}

// newOrderList is a helper method to make list of render.Renderer
func newOrderList(orders []*Order) []render.Renderer {
    list := []render.Renderer{}
    for _, order := range orders {
        list = append(list, order)
    }
    return list
}

func GetAllOrderByCustomerId(dbClient DbClient, customerId string) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        // fetch all customer orders from the DB
        orders, err := dbClient.FetchAllOrdersByCustomerId(customerId)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error("unable to fetch orders for customer", err)
            render.Render(w, r, NewInternalServerError(err))
            return
        }

        // render list of orders
        render.RenderList(w, r, newOrderList(orders))
        return

    }
}
```